# pug form input type=text attribute 'size' not working?

Tags: pug

Just learning pug from some online example and wanted to experiment restricting the size of a form's text input length to 20 characters.

```
input#first_name.form-control(type='text' placeholder='First name' name='first_name' required='true' value=(undefined===person ? '' : person.first_name))
```

I find that I can restrict the maximum number of characters a user may enter with 'maxlength=20':

```
input#first_name.form-control(type='text' maxlength=20 placeholder='First name' name='first_name' required='true' value=(undefined===person ? '' : person.first_name))
```

However, trying to limit the size of the input with 'size=20' like so:

```
input#first_name.form-control(type='text' size=20 placeholder='First name' name='first_name' required='true' value=(undefined===person ? '' : person.first_name))
```

does not change the width of the control; it stays the same, occupying the full width available to it in the browser.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the size of the box, you should include inline CSS -->style="width:20px"<-- like this:

```
input#first_name.form-control(type='text' style="witdh:20px" placeholder='First name' name='first_name' required='true' value=(undefined===person ? '' : person.first_name))
```

or in css you can :

```
#first_name{
   width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Sergi,

 #first_name{
   width:20em;
}

en el CSS funciona perfectamente.